# ASP.NET MVC - redirect after form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, redirect

I have a ASP.NET MVC website and a "Configuration" view with a form.

When I submit the form, I would like to do some stuff and then Redirect to my "Initialization" ViewResult... How to do it ?

My form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Config" }))
{
     // Some fields

     <input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

then, the "Save" action :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public async Task<RedirectToRouteResult> Save(Config websiteConfiguration)
    {
        // Do some stuff

        bool ok = await myMethod();

        if(ok)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Initialization");
        }

    }
```

I tried other possibilities but I don't manage to get it work...

Up, I still have the problem...

Comment: what error or problem are you getting with above code?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't do the redirection, it reload the "Configuration" View instead

Comment: if your "myMethod()" returns false then it will realod "ConfigurationView" and if returns true then only redirection occures, I think

Comment: But my myMethod() return true, and the redirection doesn't work...

Comment: try changing your code as I have shown in answer, if it is working or not

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this issue was with an earlier version of MVC, but I have often forgotten that the [HttpPost] label may be placed above an ActionResult in the controller and not just above a JsonResult.

So the simplest MVC-style answer would be just use Html.BeginForm and post to the ActionResult (with the [HttpPost] attribute), wherein you execute your logic, then call RedirectToAction at end after you have handled the post controller side.

This seems far easier than all the client-side fiddles, e.g. window.location.href = '' etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is what your Form Post method should look like

```
<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Respond")>
Function Respond_post(viewModel As FormsRespondModel) As ActionResult

    viewModel.form.formId = Guid.Parse(Request("formId"))

    viewModel.form.loadForm(Guid.Parse(Request("formId")))

    If (viewModel.form.formNotifications.onSuccess = "redirectOnSuccess") Then
        Return Redirect(viewModel.form.formNotifications.redirectUrl)
    End If

    Return RedirectToRoute("form_finished")
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<input id="btnSave" name="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Action_Name", "Controller_Name")'; return false;" />
```

Comment: @Amit, this will do redirection, but it is not ideal, if you are posting data to controller, then you should do redirection from controller side.

Comment: @Mark its not necessary. we can post data to controller by View easily

Comment: @Amit, my intension was not that this is wrong, I was just talking what is ideal. This place is just for sharing knowledge. Down voting doesnt make sense. No worries.